# How do I form a sqlite query to select a row if a number is in a list of numbers

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need to construct a sqlite query on Android. My DB looks similar to this:

```
ColA  ColB   ColC
1      Jim      16
2      Rob    14, 12
3      Tom    1, 4, 7
```

How do I run a query to match a number in a list of numbers?
I am trying to do this:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB FROM nametable WHERE 4 IN ColC
```

This should return row 3, but not row 2, so I can't just use "LIKE %4%".

Comment: Try with `"LIKE % 4,%"`

Comment: Should be `LIKE % 4,% OR LIKE % 4` to make it work for the last item

Comment: So there's no numbered list method? Have to use LIKE? Will those work if 4 is by itself or first?

Comment: You're right, it won't. See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be LIKE % 4,% OR LIKE % 4 OR LIKE 4, % OR LIKE 4  to make it work for the first and last item.

But that's getting complicated. Maybe you should have a child table with one to many relationship to store the numbers.

Comment: This worked, but I was hoping for an answer that wasn't string based.

Comment: I don't think there's anything non-string based unless you change the design of your database.

Comment: The design of your database is string based!  You can't have it both ways :)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer that you change your database design since it is not normalised. as follow

1. Remove column ColC from your table.
2. Create another table that have two columns:
   a. an id col that contain the id of the record in the table you have.
   b. a column that contain one number.

You tables will look like the following:

Table 1

```
ColA  ColB
 1      Jim
 2      Rob
 3      Tom
```

Table 2

```
ColA  ColB
 1     16
 2     14
 2     12
 3     1
 3     4
 3     7
```

Your select statement will be something like:

```
Select a.* from table1 a, table2 b where a.ColA == b.ColA and b.Colb = 4
```

Good Luck